# Evaluating $\int x^{x^x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

How do I evaluate
$$\int x^{x^x}\,\mathrm dx\ ?$$

I tried using integration by parts but couldn't do it.
Please solve it for me.
I found it in unsolved questions of maths calculus.

Comment: Could you show us your efforts in solving the problem?

Comment: what do you exspect?

Comment: Given the fact there does not exist a closed form for $\int x^x \mathrm{d}x$, it would amaze me if there is one for this one.

Comment: It is an unsolved question because a closed form can't be found.

Comment: Congratulations, this is now the Rahul function!

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for this according to Wolfram Alpha. That's probably why you found it on a list of open problems.

Comment: Beware, there are many answers on this site (and others) which produced closed forms to certain integrals, series and similar not exactly computable by Mathematica, Maple etc.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva. This is a very, very good point you make here. Moreover, you did prove it today more than once.

Comment: Wolfram alpha only says it cannot find a closed form. I think it is unlikely to indicate proof there is no closed form, but I could be mistaken.